# Maps and List Comprehension in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, list-comprehension, reduce

So I am fairly new to the concept of list comprehension and map/filter/reduce but feel like this can be done with few lines and less identenation:

```
ip_tlsv1_counts = {}

for filename in os.listdir(directory_path):
    if filename.endswith(LOG_FILE_EXTENSION):
        with open(os.path.join(directory_path, filename)) as file_handle:
            for line_contents in file_handle:
                line_groups = re.search(LOG_LINE_REGEX, line_contents)
                if line_groups and line_groups.group(8) == "TLSv1":
                    if not line_groups.group(2) in ip_tlsv1_counts:
                        ip_tlsv1_counts[line_groups.group(2)] = 1
                    else:
                        ip_tlsv1_counts[line_groups.group(2)] += 1

return ip_tlsv1_counts
```

Comment: So, what does it do?

Comment: You will achieve less indentation and improved clarity by using a couple of functions. I doubt comprehensions will be your saving grace here.

Comment: You could use a `Counter` instead of a `dict` for `ip_tlsv1_counts` and replace your inner `if-else` with simply `ip_tlsv1_counts[line_groups.group(2)] += 1`

Comment: And you can easily remove a block of indentation by iterating over `log_files = (f for f in os.listdir(directory_path) if f.endswith(LOG_FILE_EXTENSION)` then iterate over that: `for file in log_files:`

Comment: @Coldspeed this uses a regex that matches log entries across files and counts the occurrences of an IP address that has the field "TLSv1"

Answer (score 1):

If you work with python 3.4+, you can use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pathlib.html) module:

```
from pathlib import Path
from collections import Counter

ip_tlsv1_counts = Counter()

for path in Path(directory_path).glob('*' + LOG_FILE_EXTENSION):
    with path.open() as f1:
        for line in f1:
            line_groups = re.search(LOG_LINE_REGEX, line)
            if line_groups and line_groups.group(8) == "TLSv1":
                ip_tlsv1_counts[line_groups.group(2)] += 1

return ip_tlsv1_counts
```

Comment: this is sexy but python 3.4+ is a steep requirement from my experience :) thank you for your reply - this is definitely way sexier

Answer (score 0):

I'd use one generator function to iterate over all the files with a particular extension in a particular folder:

```
def filter_files(directory, extension):
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename.endswith(extension):
            with open(os.path.join(directory, filename)) as file_handle:
                yield file_handle
```

Then to iterate over all the lines of all those files you'd just use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` on the result of that generator.

Next you can use `re.compile(LOG_LINES_REGEX)` to get a compiled pattern, this gives some preformance boost as well as being able to use it's `.search` method in `map`:

```
log_line_re = re.compile(LOG_LINE_REGEX)
all_log_lines = itertools.chain.from_iterable(filter_files(directory_path, LOG_FILE_EXTENSION))

for line_groups in map(log_line_re.search, all_log_lines):
    if line_groups and line_groups.group(8) == "TLSv1":
        yield line_groups.group(2)
```

This will be a generator that produces all of the `line_groups.group(2)` that match the other conditions, so to count all the frequencies, you'd just construct a `Counter` with it's result.

So the final code would be like this:

```
def filter_files(directory, extension):
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename.endswith(extension):
            with open(os.path.join(directory, filename)) as file_handle:
                yield file_handle

def get_part_of_log_files():
    log_line_re = re.compile(LOG_LINE_REGEX)
    all_log_lines = itertools.chain.from_iterable(filter_files(directory_path, LOG_FILE_EXTENSION))

    for line_groups in map(log_line_re.search, all_log_lines):
        if line_groups and line_groups.group(8) == "TLSv1":
            yield line_groups.group(2)

def original_function():
    return collections.Counter(get_part_of_log_files())
```

Comment: I like this because it breaks down functionality and looks reusable although it is roughly the same line count and indentation I was curious about - thanks for your reply!